# How to modify the collection of options in step 2 when creating product configurations magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, custom-options

I have overrided this template `module-config product/view/admin/templates/catalog/product/edit/attribute/steps/attributes_values.phtml`

now i can't understand where options com from in the file and  i want to filter the values of options for example i want just to load values related to the current product. just to know my attribute of configration is created with dynamic options so can any one explain to me this code and what's the origin of options

**thanks in advance**
[image]